# Can the target of the Dissonant Whispers spell choose to use its reaction to move if it succeeds on the save?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, saving-throw, reactions

The description of the [*dissonant whispers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) spell says (PHB, p. 234):

> On a successful save, the target takes half as much damage and **doesn't have** to move away.

**Does this mean that the target can still choose to use this opportunity to use its reaction to move away?**

This is especially important if the target has feature that prevents opportunity attacks and prefer to attack at range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The target of Dissonant Whispers may take a reaction to move away.

[Dissonant Whispers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) "allows" you to take a [reaction](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Reactions):

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a
>   special action called a reaction. A reaction is an instant response to
>   a trigger of some kind, which can occur on your turn or on someone
>   else's

A failed save leaves you no option to not be forced to spend your reaction. If you succeed you may choose not to take that reaction or to take that reaction trigger that the spell grants you - as long as you have a reaction available.

> On a failed save, it [...] must immediately use
>   its reaction, if available, to move as far as its speed allows away
>   from you. On a successful save, [..] doesn’t have to move away.

Comment: In general, you don't have the option to use your reaction to do something unless a game feature gives you that option. The spell says you have to use your reaction on a failed save, but doesn't specify that you can use your reaction to move anyway on a successful one...

Comment: @V2Blast It relates in the manner that asks "why do it differently latter?" But I think one can say it is bad writting, and not intentional. I think your argument is compelling - and if the German translation wouldn't also imply that optionality, then I would change my answer.

Comment: Fair enough! I'll probably leave my own answer based on my understanding of the spell :)

Answer (score 9):

### It uses its reaction to move on a failed save; it can't do so otherwise.

The description of the [*dissonant whispers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) spell reads (PHB, p. 234; emphasis mine):

> You whisper a discordant melody that only one creature of your choice within range can hear, wracking it with terrible pain. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw. **On a failed save**, it takes 3d6 psychic damage and **must immediately use its reaction**, if available, to **move as far as its speed allows away from you**. The creature doesn’t move into obviously dangerous ground, such as a fire or a pit. **On a successful save**, the target takes half as much damage and **doesn’t have to move away.** A deafened creature automatically succeeds on the save.

As you point out, the "doesn't have to move away" phrasing seems a little ambiguous. One way to interpret it could be that, as [Akixkisu's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165354/33569) claims, a creature that succeeds on the saving throw against *dissonant whispers* can choose to use its reaction to move away anyway. However, this interpretation doesn't quite seem logical to me, due to the way reactions work.

The rules on [reactions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Reactions) state:

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a [...] reaction. A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, [...]

In general, you don't have the option to use your reaction to do something unless a game rule or feature gives you that option. (As noted later in the rule, opportunity attacks are the most common type of reaction; every creature can use its reaction to attack a creature that it can see move out of its reach.)

The *dissonant whispers* spell says you "must immediately use your reaction" to move away on a failed save. However, it doesn't specify that you can use your reaction to move anyway on a successful one; the phrasing "doesn't have to move away" does not automatically imply "can choose to move away".

As noted, all reactions occur in response to a trigger. The spell is forcing the target to use its reaction to move away in the first place, triggered by failing the Wisdom saving throw. As such, it doesn't make sense to me that succeeding on the saving throw grants the creature the ability to use their reaction to move away anyway (i.e. without a trigger); no part of the spell description clearly grants the target that choice.

---

The target of the *dissonant whispers* spell only uses its reaction to move in response to the spell if forced to do so; it can not do so willingly. This is also reinforced by a pair of (unofficial) tweets by rules designer Jeremy Crawford.

In [this February 2016 tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/703385127582171138), Crawford described movement caused by the spell as "not of your own volition":

> *Would the movement caused by a failed save on Dissonant Whispers be willing or unwilling movement?*
>
> **If a spell forces you to move, as dissonant whispers does, you're not moving of your own volition.**

In [a later tweet from February 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/834499681409343488), Crawford also said the spell "forces" movement:

> **Dissonant Whispers forces the target to move as far as its speed allows, as a reaction.** [...]

Neither description of the movement caused by *dissonant whispers* seems to characterize it as optional or willing; it's forced to move away on a failed save, but doesn't let the creature do so anyway on a success.

In general, nothing indicates that a creature can willingly use its reaction to move away from the caster of *dissonant whispers* if it succeeds on the Wisdom saving throw. Narratively, this makes sense; either the creature is seized by a momentary terror and is forced to run away, or it's not. The spell doesn't grant the creature an option that it didn't previously have if it succeeds on the saving throw.

(All that said, I suspect the situations in which a creature will want to use its reaction to move away from the caster are relatively few and far between.)